# How to create restauration point on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to produce an InstallShield for my software but support team ask me for restoration point. I do not find anything about it on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Do you know about command line to create restoration point?

Comment: Call [`SRSetRestorePoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378727.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for the help